# Finding the uniform and $L^{1}$ metric between two functions.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I know the uniform metric between two functions f and g is defined as $$d_u (f,g)=sup|f(x)-g(x)|$$
and the $L^{1}$ is defined as $$d_1 (f,g)=\sum^{n}_{i-1} |f-g|$$
Say that $$X=C[0,1]$$

Lets say I have the functions $f=e^{-x}$ and $g=1$

Will the uniform metric be 1? because it is just the largest difference between the two points?

Why does $d_1 (f,g)= \int^1 _0 |e^{-x}-0| dx$?

Specifically , why does the integral come into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your definition of the $L^1$ metric is incorrect. It should be
$$
d_1(f,g)=\int_0^1|f(x)-g(x)|\,dx.
$$
It measures the distance between two functions as the (positive) area between its graphs.

As for the other question, since $1-e^{-x}$ is increasing,
$$
d_u(e^{-x},1)=\sup_{0\le x\le1}|e^{-x}-1|=1-e^{-1}.
$$